# Model value lost on postback

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, post, postback

I have the following models:

```
class A
{
    // ...some properties

    public B InnerField { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
class B
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ..other properties
}
```

and a page that has a model Class A and inside the page I have a partial view bound to Class B inside a form.
The value of the Id (in the partial view) is set correctly to the model's Id value (different from 0) but when I submit the page the model has the Id value 0. The Id value is not modified in the component or elsewhere.

Page

```
...other parts of main page

<%using (Html.BeginForm("ModifyHotel", "Hotel",
                   FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data"}))
   {%>  
     <% Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Shared/ModifyBaseItem.ascx", 
                   new ModifyItemRequestBaseView() { ItemId = Model.Item.Id });%>
 <%}%>

...other parts of main page
```

Partial View

```
...other parts of partial view
<br/>      
    Add Photo: <%:Html.FileBoxFor(x => x.PhotoFile, null)%>            
    <br/>    
    Add Video: <%:Html.FileBoxFor(x => x.VideoFile, null)%>            
    <br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit changes" /> 
...other parts of partial view
```

What can I do to keep the value of the inner model when the post is made?

Thanks,

Comment: Include view code to help us help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Controller:**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        A model = new A() { InnerField = new B() { Id = 5 }};
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(B model)
    {
        //on postback the model should have the value 5 here
        return View();
    }
}
```

**View:**

```
@model MvcApplication11.Models.A

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.Partial("_IndexForm", Model.InnerField)

    <input type="submit" />
}
```

**Partial:**

```
@model MvcApplication11.Models.B

@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Id)
```

Comment: If add that line I get :               **The relative virtual path 'EditorTemplates/1.aspx' is not allowed here.** (I dont use Razor syntax... .)

Comment: It worked by adding a Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id) on the page, so I will mark your answer since it had a similar logic.